# Sqlite3 update variable amount of values

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I’m learning SQLite and have had some experience with mongo and mongoose. Normally in a put statement I’d run a findByIdAndUpdate command. I’d supply the data object to the call and it would update changed material. I’d use this call with a full user object.

Now in SQLite it feels like I’ve got to be explicit about what field I’m updating. In fact I’d like to manage this like in mongoose. Without knowing what user field was updated by the user during this api call, how do I determine what would need to be updated. Or, do I simply update the entire row like with mongoose.

Thanks. Committed to learning SQLite. Just want to figure this process out.

———edit

So user is email, password, first_name, last_name

I have a form that will get populated with user values on front end. Each of these can be changed at the discretion of the end user. They click update. Back in API, I’m not aware of which is changed so I don’t know what to run the insert command against. So do I do all?

What I’m trying to figure out is do I create cases for possible updates like name only or just update the whole row?

sql = ‘INSERT into Users email = ?, pwd = ?, first_name = ?, last_name = ? WHERE email = ?’

DB.run(sql, [user.email, user.pwd, user.first_name, user.last_name, req.params.email], (error)) => ()

And maybe better explained as how do you go about updating a model when one or some of those items get updated from the front end but you don’t know which ones?

Thanks

Comment: Please add sample data for the select/update you are trying to do here.

Comment: Just added an edit. Thanks